# How can I animate owlcarousel cards when slider changes left/right

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

In [this link here](https://www.66nord.com/) you will see a section that looks like in the image below:

[image]

I have managed to implement the slider using owlcarowsel.
However, how can I add the same animation as the one in the link?

So when clicking next or previous, the first image first moves with an animation, and then they all slide animated in the way that you see.

At the moment, this is how my jquery looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var owl = $(".owl-carousel");

    owl.each(function() {

        var items = ( $(this).data('items') ) ? $(this).data('items') : 1;

    $(this).owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin:30,
        stagePadding:30,
        smartSpeed: 400,
        'navText': ['< Prev','Next >'],
        onChange: function() {
            console.info('carousel change');
        },
        onChanged: function() {
            console.info('carousel changed');
        }
        //'margin': '30px',
    });
    })
});
```

Or is there perhaps another plugin that does something similar to the posted url?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see those people used complete CSS transformations to making scrolling.
If you want to work on it use 3 images in single DIV with ID then apply onclick operations Like carousel for easy animation.

Comment: Mind sending an example snippet?